Prisma with Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL - No Tables Found When Accessing from Google Cloud Run
I’m using Prisma with Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL, and I am unable to see tables when running from Google Cloud Run.
Schema.prisma snippet:
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["driverAdapters"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

Database Information:

Database name: core-db
PostgreSQL version: 15

Environment Details:
Development Environment: Successfully building schema and migrations using the following connection URL:
postgresql://postgres:{password}@{public_ip}:5432/core-db

When running locally with this URL, the app can see all entities in core-db.
Production Environment:
Deployed to Google Cloud Run with the following setup:
postgresql://{user}:{password}@{database}?host=/cloudsql/{project_id}:{location}:{instance_id}


Cloud Run Configuration: Configured to use the Cloud SQL instance
{project_id}:{loc}:{instance_id} under "Cloud SQL Connections" in
the Google Cloud Run UI.
Not using Cloud SQL Proxy or VPC.

Issue:
Despite successful connection (as indicated by logs), it returns empty set ([]) (and not an error) in core-db when running from Google Cloud Run.
Here are the logs and code snippets:
Logging Code:
export const prismaClientWithLogger = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
})

export const pingDB = async () => {
  try {
    await prismaClientWithLogger.$connect()
    console.log(`>> Prisma connected successfully with ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`)
    const tables = await prismaClientWithLogger.$queryRaw`SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public';`
    console.log(`Tables: ${JSON.stringify(tables)}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`>> Prisma failed to connect with ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}: ${error}`)
  } finally {
    await prismaClientWithLogger.$disconnect()
  }
}

Log Output:
process.env.DATABASE_URL=postgresql://{user}:{password}@{database}?host=/cloudsql/{project_id}:{loc}:{instance_id}
>> Prisma connected successfully with DATABASE_URL
Tables: []

When I run the same query locally, I see the application tables in the public schema. However, in the Cloud Run environment, the tables array is empty.
Additional Information:

I suspect there may be something incorrect with the connect string, though it seems to be enough to connect based on logs and the empty query response (not getting a connect error)
Using another user with privs makes no difference.
The error PrismaClientKnownRequestError: The table public.User does not
exist in the current database. occurs when navigating to the app,
resulting in an "Internal Server Error".


The answer "add localhost" - Correct string: postgresql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db_name}?host=/cloudsql/{connect_string}

It was missing localhost.
The correct string for Google Cloud Run using Prisma and Postgres on GCSQL is:
postgresql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db_name}?host=/cloudsql/{connect_string}

